# Why can't I see others' Buzz posts in Gwibber?

Tags: 10.10, gwibber

I've configured the built-in "broadcast accounts" feature (which, as far as I understand, is Gwibber) with my Google account for Google Buzz, but I don't receive any updates (despite there are plenty when I view Buzz through GMail site). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked "Receive Messages" found in:

Edit -> Accounts: Buzz : Advanced

I dont' have Buzz, but there are is such an option for Twitter and Facebook, and without checking them you won't get any updates.

Comment: Yes. Does not help.

Comment: Are you at least able to post messages? Or does nothing work?I guess you already tried removing and adding the account again. There is a bug-report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+bug/626023 where it's said that you have to click a confirmation link (comment nr. 6)

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely experiencing [Bug #626023](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+bug/626023). Although no fix has been released yet, you could try the workaround described in [comment #13](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+bug/626023/comments/13):

> Try copy and pasting this link into your browser:
>
> https://www.google.com/buzz/api/auth/OAuthAuthorizeToken?oauth_token=1%2FmMb9FwDmngHcuz4mqSBwlPRp3ArndpyO6HlTPSTiPcs&domain=anonymous&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fbuzz
>
> After that, copy and paste this command into a terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo sed -i -e '63 s/.*/ try:\n m["text"] = data["object"]["content"]\n except:\n m["text"] = "None"/' /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gwibber/microblog/buzz.py
> ```
>
> And see if that helps.

I only did the first part *(authenticating Gwibber by visiting that link)*, **not** the second part and even though the authentication page said "Invalid Token" it worked.